# hadoop port configuration within a firewall

Tags: hadoop, configuration, port

I have a customer where we have hadoop installation managed by us. In the current setup all the nodes in the cluster have all the ports open for each other. But the customer is quite reluctant to keep all the ports open. Can anyone let me know if any such configuration is at all possible where we instruct hadoop to use only restricted number of ports.

My Findings : I have been able to configure a test setup where I have opened only the required port as per the mentioned blog 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

But I still see the MR jobs are not executed in distributed manner.

Comment: Your link to the blog is wrong. You are pointing to the "hdfs-default.xml". Did you want to point to a specific blog? Also, what's your question? If you have already opened only a specific set of ports, then your problem is solved. What is the problem you are facing?